# Issues with VLOOKUP in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a tax table in one sheet that has a list of tax values.  For example:

```
Sheet1:  Tax Tables
    A      B      C
1  Min    Max    Taxed
   -------------------
2  50     100    10
3  100    200    20
4  200    300    30
```

In another sheet I have a gross income value of say 120 in cell A1.  What I want to do is have a vlookup (I'm assuming that's what I should use) that checks cell A1 to see if it's between the Min and Max and then outputs the taxed amount in B1.

```
Sheet2:  Income
    A      B
1  Gross FedTax
   -----------
2  120   Value from Column C goes here
```

I already have the sheet in Tax Tables set up with named spaces A:C=Min and B:C=Max
I tried doing this:

```
=AND(VLOOKUP(<A1,Min,3,False),VLOOKUP(>A1,Max,2,FALSE))
```

But not even close...
I just want to check column A in the first sheet to see if it's less than the the value in the second sheet, and check column B in the first sheet against the value in the second for if its more, then put the value in column C in the first sheet into the cell next to the value in the second sheet.

Comment: What result do you expect (or want) if the lookup value is < 50 or > 300?

Comment: it wont be, these are tax tables and what I'm showing are examples, they start at $1 and max out at $350k, No one I work with makes more than $350k or less than a dollar so it'll be fine

Comment: OK, no problem - I see you have a good answer from Doug, you can also use LOOKUP like `=LOOKUP(D2,A$2:B$5)`

Comment: yeah I was looking at all the different options and it was driving me nuts how many different ways to go about it with only very minor differences between the options lol.  but his change of the vlookup worked perfectly (after some adjustments of my table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a VLOOKUP, put your maximums and minimums in the same column.

[image]

Then use the TRUE argument, which means it looks for the next value that matches. Assuming the value you're looking up in D2, you'd put a formula like this in E2:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$5,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean put my max and min in the same column?  As in column A has both values in it?  How would that even work?

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying, except that doesn't work because if you are $1 over a value then you are in the next tax withholding, doing it your way will keep you in the lower bracket until you get closer to the next tier than the previous one

Comment: Have you tried it with some real values? It gets the next value that's more than the lookup value. It doesn't round. You really should give it a try. This is a pretty basic, well-known use of `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Yeah, I did use the real values, it rounds down.  What I ended up doing is scripting a 1 in a text editor to change it so that the min column ends in a 1 rather than a 0.  So the values are 51/10,100/10,101/20,200/20,201/30,300/30 etc.  Not quite what I was looking for, but close enough for government work lol, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is unclear what you would apply when the amount is exactly 50/100/200/300/... So i decided to include the lower limit in the interval and exclude the upper limit.

For this problem I would use a sumifs like this (you have to decide on which side to put the equal sign:
`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C;Sheet1!A:A;"<="&A1;Sheet1!B:B;">"&A1)`

This would only take those elements in column C that have a value in column A smaller than or equal to 120 and a value in column B greater than 120

Comment: It's saying there is an error, and I have no idea where the error is

Comment: maybe you need to use comma in stead of semi colon in the formula, try this: `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,"<="&A1,Sheet1!B:B,">"&A1)`

Comment: Is this still not working for you? This method will not require you to fiddle with your layout, use artificial substeps (with holes) etc.